# How can I read data from an RFID tag using SNMP/SNAP protocols?

Tags: wifi, snmp, rfid, access-point

I need to work on WIFI RFID using access points how can i do this using SNMP or SNAP protocol.
Tutorial links will be very beneficial.
Thank You!!
can the same be done using Wifi Hotspot Technology present in mobiles and laptops??

Comment: Your question is very vague. You need to "work on" this and that? Looks like just a bunch of buzzwords stacked together.
Are you looking for information about "Wi-Fi ID"?
Sorry I cannot be more helpful, but consider at least stating what you want to accomplish in more detail, as well as telling us what you've tried. Did you Google for anything before you asked?

Comment: basically working means to access/read information from active rfid tags with range of nearly 80m. these tags work on same band as WIFI (2.4Ghz) ie why are called WIFI RFID Tags.I tried googling it but didn't find much info accept that in some articles it was written that i can use these protocols to access them, but no mention of how to use them, ie what i basically need to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only hope is to dive into the vendors' documentation like below,

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/solutions/Enterprise/Mobility/wifich6.html

As such information is product/vendor-specific, post it to a general forum like SO is not your best choice.